# Syntax error when compiling a PL/SQL procedure due to BEGIN TRY and END CATCH sentences;

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've the following code as part of PL/SQL procedure:

```
OPEN c1;
FETCH c1 INTO vr_usuario;
WHILE c1%found LOOP
    BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO users_unit_changes ( <--- Error 1 happens here
        iduserunitchange,
        nif,
        inspectiondate,
        workdate
    ) VALUES (
        seq_userunitchanges.NEXTVAL,
        vr_usuario.iddni,
        v_fecha,
        NULL
    );
 
  
    FETCH c1 INTO vr_usuario;
       END TRY;
      BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH; <--- Error 2 happens here
END LOOP;
```

I want to achieve that if the insertion fails for whatever reason, the execution passes to the following row existing on c1 cursor.

But I'm getting the following errors when I try to compile the procedure (where the error happens is marked on code):

Error(34,9): PLS-00103: "INSERT" symbol has been found when one of the following ones was expected:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ";" has been substituted by "INSERT" to continue.

Error(50,9): PLS-00103: "END" symbol has been found when one of the following ones was expected:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ";" has been substituted by "END" to continue.

What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: I doubt if PL/SQL supports TRY/CATCH. It is more about SQL Server

Comment: [Oracle PL/SQL documentation is here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/index.html). Please check it before asking syntax questions.

Answer (score 3):

`TRY` and `CATCH` are not valid PL/SQL syntax.

You want:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (
  v_fecha    users_unit_changes.inspectiondate%TYPE DEFAULT SYSDATE
)
IS
  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT DUMMY AS iddni FROM DUAL;
  vr_usuario C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO vr_usuario;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO users_unit_changes (
        iduserunitchange,
        nif,
        inspectiondate,
        workdate
      ) VALUES (
        seq_userunitchanges.NEXTVAL,
        vr_usuario.iddni,
        v_fecha,
        NULL
      );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN -- Name the exception to catch
        -- Handle the exception
        NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w4y6Ngyi)

Answer (score 1):

Errors you got are related to invalid syntax, as you've already heard.

---

Consider using "simpler" cursor `FOR` loop as - with it - Oracle does most of the job for you - you don't have to declare cursor variable, open cursor, fetch from it, worry about exiting the loop nor close the cursor.

You do, though, still need an inner `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` block which will let loop to continue in case of an error.

```
DECLARE
   -- just guessing; you didn't explain what V_FECHA is
   v_fecha  users_unit_changes.inspectiondate%TYPE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
   FOR vr_usuario IN (SELECT iddni FROM your_table)
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO users_unit_changes (iduserunitchange,
                                         nif,
                                         inspectiondate,
                                         workdate)
              VALUES (seq_userunitchanges.NEXTVAL,
                      vr_usuario.iddni,
                      v_fecha,
                      NULL);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            -- This ("OTHERS") handles any error that might happen. If you know which
            -- errors you expect, handle them. I'm just displaying IDDNI that failed
            -- and error which says *why* it failed
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vr_usuario.iddni || ': ' || SQLERRM);
            NULL;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

---

On the other hand, loop is usually row-by-row processing and it can be really slow; switch to set processing, if you can. I don't know *which* errors you might be expecting, but you can try with a `merge` and see what happens. If it actually works, for large data sets it should be way faster than a loop version.

```
MERGE INTO users_unit_changes a
     USING table_that_contains_iddni b
        ON (a.nif = b.iddni)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (iduserunitchange,
               nif,
               inspectiondate,
               workdate)
       VALUES (seq_userunitchanges.NEXTVAL,
               b.iddni,
               v_fecha, --> once again, I don't know what it is
               NULL);
```